# How do I unload a userform without closing everything else?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two userforms (`frmDatastation1` and `frmDatastation2`). When the user clicks on cmdbutton on `frmDatastation1`, the first form becomes hidden (`frmDatastation.hide`) and the second appears (`frmDatastation.show`).  That works fine. When the user is done with `frmDatastation2`, I'd like to go back to `frmDatastation1` and unload `frmdatastation2` (to erase all it's content to use it again later from `frmDatastation1`). But when I unload `frmDatastation2`, everything closes (even `frmDatastation1`).

Here's my code in `frmDatastation2`:

```
frmDatastation1.TextBox1.Text = ""  'this is to reset my textbox not sure it's needed
Me.Hide 'hiding frmDatastation2
Unload frmDatastation1
frmDatastation1.Show vbModeless ' to be able to continue with the next step
frmDatastation1.TextBox1.SetFocus
Unload frmDatastation2 'when this line is executed, it closes everything (even frmDatastation1)
```

Comment: Keep using `.Hide` instead of Unloading the userform.  Then if you want a blank form whenever you bring it up, use the Userform event `Userform_Activate()` to blank out the fields so it can be reused. It performs the `Activate` event every time the form is shown (`userform.show`).

Comment: Why you have this `Unload frmDatastation1`?

Comment: @EganWolf: I used Unload frmDatastation1 to "reset" the from. I'm not sure if it 's a good idea however.

Comment: @tigeravatar: Thanks, I like your idea.  However if I do that, I can't "reset" what my combobox (in frmDatastation) shows (it's text or value) since it's style is set as a dropdownlist (I don't want people to modify it's content). Any ideay how I can reset the combobox value (what the user sees, ex:Pick your prefered juice..)

Comment: `combobox.listindex = -1`

Comment: well, -1 puts the combobox as blank.  to show a value (maybe your "Pick your preferred juice" is the first option?) you would set it to the ListIndex of that text you want to display.  0 is the first line in the combobox so you would use `combobox.listindex = 0`

Comment: @tigeravatar: Yeah, I got a blank combobox (which is not that bad). I now have to decide if I want a "dummy" choice ("pick your preferred jucie") or a blank combobox.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use objects instead of using the global/default instance.

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Dim parentForm As frmDatastation1
    Set parentForm = New frmDatastation1
    parentForm.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

There's no need to really `Unload` anything then - the object reference `parentForm` will die when execution exits `DoSomething` and the object goes out of scope.

```
Sub ShowChildForm()
    Dim childForm As frmDatastation2
    Set childForm = New frmDatastation2
    childForm.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

To make your two objects "talk" to each other, you need to pass object references around. Say the child form needs a reference to the parent, it could have a property like this:

```
Private parentForm As frmDatastation1

Public Property Get Parent() As frmDatastation1
    Set Parent = parentForm
End Property

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal value As frmDatastation1)
    Set parentForm = value
End Property
```

And then the parent form could do this:

```
Sub ShowChildForm()

    Dim childForm As frmDatastation2
    Set childForm = New frmDatastation2
    Set childForm.Parent = Me
    childForm.Show vbModal

    textbox1.Text = childForm.textbox12.Text

End Sub
```

...While the child form could access its parent form like this:

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Me.Caption = Parent.textbox1.Text
End Sub
```

If you want to be able to access the properties of a form that's closed but not yet unloaded/discarded, don't *close* it - just *hide* it instead (you'll need to implement the behavior in `QueryClose` to prevent discarding the object when the user "X-out"'s of the form).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  This option is a little more elaborated and my VBA knowledge are not that great... I will take some time to think about it and I'll give you my comments soon.  Thanks for trying to help !

Comment: @Matt: I think I understand the idea. You execute what you have to do and at the end the form "disappear".  It wanted to test this so I created a new button in my frmDatastation1 which called ShowChilForm (I copied the ShowChildForm Sub in the frmDatastation1). However when I tried it I got an error '1004' (on this line: Set childForm = New frmDatastation2).  I think there something I don't understand...

Comment: I might be missing some context - is `frmDatastation2` a UserForm?

Comment: Yes Matt, frmDatastation2 is a UserForm.

Comment: Matt: there's probably something different (and wrong) in my userforms.  I created a new workbook with UserForm1 and UserFrom2 and your code works: it creates a new userfom when I click the cmdbutton.  However, it doesn't hide (or unload) the previous form and it creates a new one everytime I switch back and forth (the button on UserForm1 creates UserForm2 and the button on UserForm2 createds UserFrom1).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish then.