# VBA excel printing to printer with user form

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have a userform, that when filled out, has a command button at the bottom. When the button is clicked, it copies the data to worksheet2, and then copies the row information into worksheet 4, which is a form, closes the userform.and opens up the welcome userform then i want it to print worksheet4.

Here is the code I have. The print function will not work.

```
Private Sub SavePrintButton_Click()

EditAdd

Sheet4.Activate
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = TextBox1.Value
Range("b2").Value = myValue

Unload Me

Function PrintOneSheet()
      Sheets("Sheet4").PrintOut 
End Function

WelcomeUserForm.Show



End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `Unload Me`. Anything after that is unreachable. Also... you can't have a `Function` inside a `Sub`. The code you're showing won't even *compile*, let alone *run*.

Comment: Not true about the Unload Me. Several other areas have many lines of code that work fine after wards. If i can have a function inside a sub, how would i edit it to make what i am trying to accomplish work?

Comment: `Unload Me` *unloads the current instance*. You're using it as if it were  `Me.Hide`, but it's more than that and you're misusing it. My code compiles, yours doesn't. Take the advice you get. Also you shouldn't be working off the default instance of forms, that will bite you in the rear end one day or another.

Comment: Just because you managed to get an unloading instance to "work" elsewhere in your code doesn't mean that it's a good idea. Think about what you're doing there for a minute.  You're telling the runtime *that it should unload the object* then have more code afterwards. Using the default instances of forms like that can create all kinds of dodgy behavior.  Treat them like you would ***any other class*** - use hard references to object instances.  I'm guessing you'd be surprised at the unloading order if you put some `Debug.Print` statements in the `Terminate` handlers...

Comment: OP, `Unload Me` is the last line of normal code that you should execute in your form (some forms have procedures that are called when e.g. the form is being unloaded; but yours apparently does not). `Unload Me` is not "here's a week's notice", it's the equivalent of having your stuff packed up and being ushered out of the office. In my answer below I just tweaked your code so it can more or less work. I didn't magically transform it into good code.

Answer (score 1):

Your "PrintOneSheet" function is embedded in SavePrintButton_Click. Move the "end sub" after "unload me" and insert "call PrintOneSheet" above "unload me". I've taken the liberty of adding a "Me.Hide" line since you apparently want the current form to go away before you show WelcomeUserForm. It still gets unloaded once it's not needed. Meantime if for any reason you want to go back to it to correct something, you can do so by simply showing it again.

```
Private Sub SavePrintButton_Click()
    Dim myValue As Variant

    EditAdd

    Sheet4.Activate
    myValue = TextBox1.Value
    Sheet4.Range("b2").Value = myValue

    Call PrintOneSheet
    Me.Hide
    WelcomeUserForm.Show
    Unload Me
End Sub

Function PrintOneSheet()
    Sheets("Sheet4").PrintOut
End Function
```

On another note, is Sheet4 always going to be called "Sheet4"? Sheet4 is a direct call to the object id, "Sheet4" is a call to one of its properties (its name). You should be consistent in your references or someday you'll change something apparently minor and chaos will break loose.

Comment: Upvoted, except there's something terribly wrong about unloading an object (`Me`) that's holding a reference to another (`WelcomeUserForm`)... although yeah, it's the default instance so it lives in global scope... gosh this is so wrong... I'd make whoever is responsible for showing this form, responsible for showing a new instance of a `WelcomeUserForm` when this one closes. And there's no need to `Unload` it if the caller is creating an actual instance of the form. Working with default instances is just wrong and bug-prone, in so many ways.

Comment: Why is `PrintOneSheet` a `Function`?  It doesn't return anything (except the implict `Empty`), and if it did you're explicitly discarding the return value with `Call PrintOneSheet`.

Comment: I tried your instance, with the unload me at the end, the welcomeuserfrom does not come up.The SaveButton_CLick() is a save button in a different userform. Idea being that when it is clicked, the form adds/edits the data in sheet2, makes sheet4 activate and populates thecells  accordingly, prints sheet4, closes the current userform(unload Me) and opens WelcomeUserForm. I just added sheet4.printout prior to unload me and it worked, and welcomeuserform.show after it.

Comment: So my question is, if i want to close the current userform im in and load another, what would i use instead of unload me?

Comment: OP, your original code *would not compile*. I pasted it into a userform, added TextBox1 and SaveprintButton. I showed it, and when I clicked SaveprintButton got an error saying "Compile error: Expected End Sub" because your code had a function embedded in it. So I pulled that out. Now you've tested the new code and you understand you don't need the function, because sheet4.printout does the job. Congratulations! Now read what @Mat's Mug has been telling you. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138993/how-do-i-unload-a-userform-without-closing-everything-else)

Comment: So what is the best way to close a userform and open a new one threw the command button if your saying unload(me) is correct? If I used me.hide, the current data in the userform will still be present when reopened. If im doing it completely wrong, which it sounds like I am, id like to learn how to do it right. TIA

Comment: You don't need to unload it. You create an instance (dimension it and set a reference to a new instance of it)  and show and hide that as required. You use userform events to determine whether it should show the same data as before or be reset to blank ready for new data. You can even run multiple instances simultaneously. There's a wealth of info available: go read up. I gave you a link to one of @Mat's Mug's posts covrring it.

Comment: @J.Wichtner the data will still be present because you're working off the default instance. You need to `New` up your own instance instead, so that the state belongs to that instance you completely control the lifetime of - vs putting state in a global object (the default instance) that VBA resurrects whenever it feels like.

Answer (score 0):

I have reworked the code a bit. Does this look more like it should? I got rid of all unload.me in my vba.

```
Private Sub SavePrintButton_Click()

EditAdd

Sheet6.Activate
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = TextBox1.Value
Range("b2").Value = myValue

ClearForm
Me.Hide

Sheet6.PrintOut

WelcomeUserForm.Show

MsgBox "New Run Added"

MsgBox "Run Sent to Printer"

End Sub
```